# A non cauchy-schwarz approach to the question: Prove that if $\sum{a_k^2}$ converges then $\sum{a_k/k}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I wanted to know how to solve this question without the use of the cauchy-schwarz inequality and using more standard methods/tests (such as ratio test, comparison test etc.) for convergence/divergence if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use CS inequality

Comment: $ab\le{1\over 2}(a^2+b^2)$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I haven't learn't the cauchy-schwarz inequality yet and so feel that there may be an alternative route through the problem. Is there a different solution that sticks to the standard tests for convergence/divergence only?

Comment: Use the Comparison Test.   $|a_k|(1/k)\le (1/2)(a_k^2+ 1/k^2)$ from my previous comment (which is proved from $0\le (a-b)^2$)..

Answer (score 4):

Hint: (assuming all $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$)

Just note that according to [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) you have
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{a_k}{k} \right| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k^2}}\cdot \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^N a_k^2}$$

**Edit after OP changed the question** to "non-Cauchy-Schwarz":

You may use the inequality GM-QM (geometric/quadratic mean)
or you derive directly that

- $|a_k\cdot\frac{1}{k}| \leq \frac{a_k^2 + \frac{1}{k^2}}{2}$

$$\Rightarrow \left|\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{a_k}{k} \right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^N \left|\frac{a_k}{k} \right| \leq \frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{k=1}^Na_k^2+ \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^2} \right)$$

Now the required result follows by comparison.

Comment: Thanks. But is there an alternative solution you can think of perhaps just using the standard tests for convergence/divergence?

Comment: There aren't restrictions on $a_k$ or $b_k$.

Comment: @pahad2000 I changed the solution according to your change of the question.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), you have

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{k} \right)^2 \le \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k^2$$

and both series on the right side converge.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit tentative to apply the cauchy-schwarz inequality. Could there be an alternative solution that sticks to the standard tests for convergence/divergence only?